# Custom buttons in searchview widget (in actionbar)

Tags: android, searchview

Is it possible to cutomize the searchview widget as to add a button inside the widget?

When adding `android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer"` to the searchable config file a microphone appears.. but i'd like to add an aditional (my own) button in the view to open a dialog.

Is it possible and can someone point me in the right direction?

I am targeting 4.0 and up

Answer (score 2):

The question is around 1 year old by the date of my answer. But if someone is looking for such thing:

```
int parentLayoutId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_plate", null, null);
LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) mSearchView.findViewById(parentLayoutId);
```

`search_plate` is the layout holder of close button and voice search. 
Then add all views you want to the `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Since a private SearchView class method is setting submit_area Visibility.Gone so we can't do much about it.

A quick dirty trick is to set of the default buttons enabled and then set its width and height to 0. Setting Visibility didn't work so have to set height/width.

I enabled search button and then set its height/width to zero.

int submit_areaId = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/submit_area", null, null);

ImageView submitImage = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(search_go_btnId);

searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 0);

submitImage.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);